# Stop Resizing Text in Mobile

Tags: css, mobile, text, resize

Folks,

So I am trying to eliminate the auto-text resizing in mobile browsers from my website ([boxangeles.com](http://boxangeles.com)) as it makes the layout look horrible, IMO.

It seems the sections that have the issue are referencing this CSS --

```
#newPost {
background-color: white; 
border: 1px solid #ec0000;
border-radius: 7px;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 115%;
margin-bottom: 15px;
padding: 15px;
width: 690px;
margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;}

#newPost img {
border: 1px solid #ec0000;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;}

#newPost a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;}
```

And the text sections that work fine are using this CSS --

```
.post-block {
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid #ec0000;
border-radius: 7px;
font-size: 20px;
float: left;
height: 165px;
line-height: 115%;
margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
padding: 10px;
width: 700px;}

p.post-block a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;}

.post-block a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;}

.post-block .thumb {
background: url(images/thumbBg.jpg) no-repeat;
float: left;
height: 150px;
padding: 4px;
margin: 2px 7px 2px 2px;
width: 150px;}
```

I found this --

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">`

on StackOverflow, which stopped the text from resizing, in the #newpost sections, but now that normal size text only takes up about half the usual space (on the left side) ...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this link: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

You should use media queries so that you can assign different CSS code based on screen size. Here is a basic setup:

```
/* Put your original CSS code here */

@media(min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    /* Put your mobile only code here */
}
```